# How do I use 2 columns of a CSV file in a single command?

Tags: powershell, powercli

I want to use serverip and ram which is in same csv file in a command which have `$serverip` and `$ram` . So I want to use corresponding serverip and ram value in foreach loop at once.

csv file is like this:

```
sw02111 8
sw02014 4
sw02020 16
```

now i want to use this value to below command in for-each loop:

```
Set-VM -VM $serverip -MemoryMB $ram
```

Comment: It depeneds on which kind of foreach loop you are using. Can you share that full part of the code. It would also help to see the headers of your CSV file.

Answer (score 3):

If your CSV file has a header row of RAM, ServerIP then you could do the following

```
Import-CSV YourFile.csv -header serverip,ram -delimiter ' ' | ForEach-Object {
    Set-VM -VM $_.ServerIP -MemoryMB $_.RAM
}
```

**Explanation:**

- `Import-CSV` loads the CSV file in to a PowerShell object and then passes it via the pipeline to `ForEach-Object`.
- Based on your CSV sample in your question I've explicitly defined in the `Import-CSV` command the header as `serverip,ram` and the delimiter as a space character. If your CSV is formatted differently these may need to be changed or these settings might not be necessary at all if you have a well defined CSV.
- Each item in the object is evaluated one at a time and represented in the loop as `$_`.
- Because the CSV has ServerIP and RAM headers the object has the equivalent properties which are accessed via `.`

Comment: The OP might need to use the -header and -delimiter  options  given the CSV  shown.